# Average numbers in my SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, average

I have a question regarding my SQL query. Below you will see my database:

[image: My database]

And I have the following query right now:

```
SELECT enquete_vraag,enquete_antwoord,docent,vak,semesterstart
FROM ENQUETE_ANTWOORD
LEFT JOIN KDV ON ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.kdv_ID = KDV.kdv_ID
LEFT JOIN DOCENT ON KDV.docent_ID = DOCENT.docent_ID
LEFT JOIN VAK ON KDV.vak_ID = VAK.vak_ID
LEFT JOIN ENQUETE_VRAAG ON ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.enquete_vraag_ID = ENQUETE_VRAAG.enquete_vraag_ID
WHERE DOCENT.docent_ID = variableDocentID AND VAK.vak = variableVak
```

And I display the returned data in a `datagridview`:

[image: Datagridview]

Now the `datagridview` shows all questions that are being answered by all students. What I want is the `average` for each question and only show that. So you have 1 row that has question 6 with the average answer and question 7 with the average answer and so on, how do I achieve that in my SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you should do something like this

```
SELECT enquete_vraag,AVG(enquete_antwoord) enquete_antwoord,docent,vak,semesterstart 
FROM ENQUETE_ANTWOORD 
LEFT JOIN KDV ON ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.kdv_ID = KDV.kdv_ID 
LEFT JOIN DOCENT ON KDV.docent_ID = DOCENT.docent_ID 
LEFT JOIN VAK ON KDV.vak_ID = VAK.vak_ID 
LEFT JOIN ENQUETE_VRAAG ON ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.enquete_vraag_ID = ENQUETE_VRAAG.enquete_vraag_ID 
WHERE DOCENT.docent_ID = variableDocentID AND VAK.vak = variableVak 
GROUP BY enquete_vraag, docent,vak,semesterstart
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT enquete_vraag,AVG(enquete_antwoord) as [enquete_antwoord]
FROM ...
GROUP BY enquete_vraag
```

The problem then, of course, becomes which `vak` etc to choose.... Because of translation, it is not easy for me to guess at which value means what, so it is hard to advise on that. You *might* be able to include the extra values in the `GROUP BY` clause (if they are the same for all the matching rows); or you *might* be able to take a `MIN` / `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

just add avg function in your code.

```
...AVG(enquete_antwoord)...
```

write above code it gives you the correct answer